# How can I get two different binary trees of two different types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary-tree, typedef

For an array if I want an array of integers it's:

```
int anArray[];
```

For an array of strings it is:

```
string anArray[];
```

I have a binary search tree template that allows the type to be chosen using a typedef:

```
typedef desiredType TreeItemType; // desired type of tree items i.e. string, int, etc.
```

How can I get two different trees of two different types?  Right now the only way I see possible is to write all the supporting code twice with different file names and setting the typedef's.  There has to be a way to set the typedef desiredType in a method or something.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

why not turn it into a [templated class](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Templated_Binary_Tree.shtml), seeing as your using C++? this allows any number of permutations of types, and remove any problems that might occur with a typedef'd type(aliased type).